# In which table does Amazon Cognito data gets saved - Beginner

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-mobile-hub

I used `AWS Cognito` to authenticate users in my iOS application. The users of the app will have to enter the email, phone number and their name in order to register and `Amazon` will be sending a SMS to authenticate the phone number.

All of these are working fine. I have few questions and they are :

1.) I want to know where these data are getting saved ? It's not there in the Dynamo DB (However, I found the list of users in `AWS Cognito --> Federated Identities --> Users` , but not in a Table in`DynamoDB`)

2.) Now, once the users are authenticated, I am allowing the users to interact with the application. The first task will be that the users will have to complete their profile. I want to know if in case if an user is NOT authenticated will he be able to complete his profile ? Ideally, he should not be allowed. But is this happening automatically ?

EDIT

[image]

Comment: Is the profile you're referring to on your end? If not, are you using user pools, *not* federated identities?

Comment: No its federated Identities. By meaning profile i meant some attributes the user is going to enter the Database (Like profile picture, and his hobbies).

Comment: The reason I ask is that by default, federated identities does not support profiles, only leveraging public providers (facebook, twitter, google...etc.), your own back end, or guest access to get credentials to access AWS resources. Federated identities does not do SMS phone number validation, either. Is this an extension you made, or from Cognito? If it's coming from Cognito, it would be user pools, that's the side that supports user profiles, phone number validation...etc.

Comment: I have added the image in the post above. I think its User pool

Comment: I have a suspicion that they store users in Directory Service (LDAP), mostly because of similar attributes like birth date and picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You are correct, data is not stored inside dynamo for user profiles. Cognito has an internal data store in which user data is persisted. This can be viewed and edited (as an admin) through the 'Users' tab of your user pool.

2) They should not be able to, and it is not happening automatically. The only way to update attributes stored against a user is as an admin (which the user shouldn't be able to do) or with the token that they get from signing in, so what you're aiming for is very do-able.

Comment: I need to know how I could make it mandatory for the user to validate himself via SMS (Using amazon cognito) prior to communicating with DynamoDB ? Is this automatically handled by Amazon ?

Comment: If you want your users to be able to use any AWS resources (ex: DDB, S3), once the user is signed in, you will need to acquire AWS Credentials using Cognito Federated Identities. That process is described here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's point, if you have SMS MFA required in your pool config (set from the console), they won't be logged in until they have completed that MFA. Only then do they get the token with which they can update their attributes or give to federated identities to access AWS resources. Cognito User Pools does not store data on DynamoDB, though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I dont think SMS MFA is required for authentication. I think that it is only used in 2-way authentication, where the user will get a SMS to confirm if the  login is invalid. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: SMS MFA is a second step of authentication after a successful login. If the user login fails, the process stops there, it does not kick off SMS MFA.